# PBI Report Server - Embed without authentication

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am trying to incorporate a report on the company's intranet page, but I would like no authentication to be requested.

I tried the way below (pass login by parameter in the url) that I saw in a post but it didn't work. Is there any way to do it?

```
<iframe src="http://myusername@mypassword:MyServerRport/relatorios/powerbi/Inteligencia/Cashback?rs:embed=true" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Versions used:**

- Microsoft Power BI Report Server (May 2020)
- SQL SERVER 2019 Developer Edition (15.2002.4709.1) (Both in PT-BR)

Comment: Just to note, if you are using this in a Live intranet page, and the if one or both of Report Server and SQL Server are Developer versions then this is not allowed under the MS License terms. It is for none Production environments only.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I have a SQL SERVER license and REPORT SERVER are using the developer version to validate the environment. I have already contacted an MS representative.